# Android backs to previous activity when passing byte[]

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am getting hell annoying error:

```
12-12 03:46:48.241 23461-23461/com.cronline.haito.projectbeggining W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-12 03:46:48.241 23461-23461/com.cronline.haito.projectbeggining E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
12-12 03:46:48.245 23461-23461/com.cronline.haito.projectbeggining E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
12-12 03:46:48.245 23461-23461/com.cronline.haito.projectbeggining D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

It happens when i try to open certain images and when it happens it backs of to the previous activity.

And I have no idea whatsoever what is causing it. It happens only when passing some of the photos. But i can't find difference between them, because I have almost 2 same image, one cause problems and other don't. They have same resolution 685x960 and size of 60KB.

The code:

```
Passing to the second activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditorActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", BitmapTransformer.compress(bitmap));
startActivity(intent);
```

Compress and decompress methods:

```
public static byte[] compress(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
public static Bitmap decompress(byte[] data){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

And receiving an image:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
byte[] imageAsByteArray = intent.getExtras().getByteArray("image");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapTransformer.decompress(imageAsByteArray);
```

Images causing problems:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ylwhbpdx41w6x2u/AAAUtQsYppge5kb7dEBHuouHa?dl=0

Comment: Do not send images into the intent. Save image to internal storage, then pass the path

Comment: Well... That works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to save your Bitmap to file and send only path of file name, and then read from path again. It is pos